# How to get acces to the second <p> in selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, tags

I'm new in Python and Selenium. I have this code:

```
<div class="Product_ProductInfo__23DMi">
   <p style="font-weight: bold;">4.50</p>
   <p>Bread</p>
   <p>390 g</p>
</div>
```

I want to get access to the second `<p>` tag and get its value (I mean `Bread`).

For the first `<p>` tag, I used:

`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="Product_ProductInfo__23DMi"]/p')`

But I don't know how to get to the other one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `find_elements_by_css_selector()` function and then selecting the second element of it.

```
a = self.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="Product_ProductInfo__23DMi"]')
second_p = a.find_elements_by_css_selector('p')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-of-type(<index>)` (index starts with 1) which is you can say css property.

```
a = self.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="Product_ProductInfo__23DMi"] > p:nth-of-type(2)')
```